# Label only extreme legends in a map

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a coefficient number for each state of Argentina and I want to label the extreme higher values as "Similar Income" and label the lowest as "Different Income".
I have something like this

```
ggplot(arg_sf) +
  geom_sf(col = NA, aes(fill=(VALORES))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "green4")
```

[image]

So far this is my result and it is exactly what i want, but i would like to remove the legends and add two in the extremes, with the text i mentioned before: green4="Similar Income" and green="Different Income"

Do you have any hint about how to solve it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this (assuming you still want to maintain the gradient in the figure):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1

nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
ggplot(nc) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA))+
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "green4", 
                        breaks=range(nc$AREA), guide="legend", 
                        labels=c("Similar Income", "Different Income"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>